# Detecting a function in C++ at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, static, macros

Is there a way, presumably using templates, macros or a combination of the two, that I can generically apply a function to different classes of objects but have them respond in different ways if they do not have a specific function?

I specifically want to apply a function which will output the size of the object (i.e. the number of objects in a collection) if the object has that function but will output a simple replacement (such as "N/A") if the object doesn't. I.e.

```
NO_OF_ELEMENTS( mySTLMap ) -----> [ calls mySTLMap.size() to give ] ------>  10
NO_OF_ELEMENTS( myNoSizeObj ) --> [ applies compile time logic to give ] -> "N/A"
```

I expect that this might be something similar to a static assertion although I'd clearly want to compile a different code path rather than fail at build stage.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato: with C++11 knocking at the door, there are new opportunities that have not been explored in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and advice. Sadly I can't use C++11 or Boost in my solution due to the clients limitations, which is a shame. Nevertheless, with the info you've all provided, I was able to get this going and extend it to provide a function to stream out either the size() or "<N/A>" using a private, embedded template class, partially specialised for the 'true' condition. I am now very pleased!! Thank you all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to have a generic test to see if a class has a certain member function. This can be accomplished in C++ using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE). In C++11 it's pretty simple, since you can use `decltype`:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_size {
private:
    template <typename U>
    static decltype(std::declval<U>().size(), void(), std::true_type()) test(int);
    template <typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);
public:
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0)) type;
    enum { value = type::value };
};
```

If you use C++03 it is a bit harder due to the lack of `decltype`, so you have to abuse `sizeof` instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_size {
private:
    struct yes { int x; };
    struct no {yes x[4]; };
    template <typename U>
    static typename boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(static_cast<U*>(0)->size(), void(), int()) == sizeof(int), yes>::type test(int);
    template <typename>
    static no test(...);
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes) };
};
```

Of course this uses `Boost.Enable_If`, which might be an unwanted (and unnecessary) dependency. However writing `enable_if` yourself is dead simple:

```
template<bool Cond, typename T> enable_if;
template<typename T> enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
```

In both cases the method signature `test<U>(int)` is only visible, if `U` has a `size` method, since otherwise evaluating either the `decltype` or the `sizeof` (depending on which version you use) will fail, which will then remove the method from consideration (due to `SFINAE`. The lengthy expressions `std::declval<U>().size(), void(), std::true_type()` is an abuse of C++ comma operator, which will return the last expression from the comma-separated list, so this makes sure the type is known as `std::true_type` for the C++11 variant (and the `sizeof` evaluates `int` for the C++03 variant). The `void()` in the middle is only there to make sure there are no strange overloads of the comma operator interfering with the evaluation.

Of course this will return true if `T` has a `size` method which is callable without arguments, but gives no guarantees about the return value. I assume wou probably want to detect only those methods which don't return void. This can be easily accomplished with a slight modification of the `test(int)` method:

```
// C++11
template <typename U>
static typename std::enable_if<!is_void<decltype(std::declval<U>().size())>::value, std::true_type>::type test(int);
//C++03
template <typename U>
static typename std::enable_if<boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(static_cast<U*>(0)->size()) != sizeof(void()), yes>::type test(int);
```

Comment: interesting... but what's the `void()` for ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: the `void()` is not strictly needed. However it's there to make sure that no strange things happen with overloaded comma operators (unlikely in this case, but that is the general way I use for checking all methodexistances, so I thought I'd keep it in).

Comment: I thought briefly it could be the case, but it seems just more like that it was a cruft forgotten when you added `true_type` :) As for going the `decltype` way, it makes things so easy for functions, that it's easier to define traits as `constexpr` functions or just bypass traits and use it directly, see my answer :)

Comment: How different is above from this C++ 11's (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) ?

Answer (score 10):

There was a discussion about the abilities of `constexpr` some times ago. It's time to use it I think :)

It is easy to design a trait with `constexpr` and `decltype`:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(std::declval<T>().size(), true) has_size(int) { return true; }

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_size(...) { return false; }
```

So easy in fact that the trait loses most of its value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
auto print_size(T const& t) -> decltype(t.size(), void()) {
  std::cout << t.size() << "\n";
}

void print_size(...) { std::cout << "N/A\n"; }

int main() {
  print_size(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
  print_size(1);
}
```

[In action](http://ideone.com/4DNfK):

```
3
N/A
```

Comment: I can see the use of `void()` in Grizzly's answer, but here? Seems superfluous, since there will be no second parameter to a "possible" comma operator anyways. A left-over?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the better way to write the trait. Compared to the "common" approach of capsulating it in a struct you have only avoided writing the struct around the methods and putting the result value in an enum or a `constexpr bool`. On the other hand `has_size` has a less desiarable signature this way IMO. Same gores for `print_size`.

Comment: @Xeo: the `void()` in `print_size` is used to give it a returnvalue of `void` instead of `decltype(declval<T>().size())`

Comment: @Grizzly: I see it as a different way. It's certainly new, so I expect some resistance. I gave a few reasons while I think that traits could be moved to functions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896637/why-are-type-traits-implemented-with-specialized-template-structs-instead-of-con/8900021#8900021). A few years ago I would have embraced your classes, but now I am trying to explore C++11 possibilities, especially in reducing the clutter and getting new functionalities.

Comment: Note that you could reduce the clutter even more by using the trailing return type: `auto print_size(T const& t) -> decltype(t.size(), void())`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using a technique called [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982808/c-sfinae-examples). In your specific case you could implement that using [Boost.Concept Check](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm). You'd have to write your own concept for checking for a `size`-method. Alternatively you could use an existing concept such as [`Container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/reference.htm#container-concepts), which, among others, requires a `size`-method.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer didn't get top votes. SFINAE is the way to go here, IMHO.

Comment: @AzzA: Even though I dislike the "You can do something like <code>" style of answers, most answers here actually show SFINAE practices...

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
template< typename T>
int getSize(const T& t)
{
    return -1;
}

template< typename T>
int getSize( const std::vector<T>& t)
{
    return t.size();
}

template< typename T , typename U>
int getSize( const std::map<T,U>& t)
{
    return t.size();
}

//Implement this interface for 
//other objects
class ISupportsGetSize
{
public:
    virtual int size() const= 0;
};

int getSize( const ISupportsGetSize & t )
{
    return t.size();
}

int main()
{
    int s = getSize( 4 );
    std::vector<int> v;
    s = getSize( v );

    return 0;
}
```

basically the most generic implementation is always return -1 or "NA" but for vector and maps it will return the size. As the most general one always matches there is never a build time failure

Answer (score 2):

**Here you go.**  Replace `std::cout` with the output of your liking.

```
template <typename T>
class has_size
{
    template <typename C> static char test( typeof(&C::size) ) ;
    template <typename C> static long test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

template<bool T>
struct outputter
{
    template< typename C >
    static void output( const C& object )
    {
        std::cout << object.size();
    }
};

template<>
struct outputter<false>
{
    template< typename C >
    static void output( const C& )
    {
        std::cout << "N/A";
    }
};


template<typename T>
void NO_OF_ELEMENTS( const T &object )
{
    outputter< has_size<T>::value >::output( object );
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `object.size()` will provoke a failure. You need to delegate the printing to a SFINAE'd structure.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes!  I overlooked that.  Thanks.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>



template<typename T>                                                                
struct has_size                                                                 
{                                                                                   
  typedef char one;                                                                 
  typedef struct { char a[2]; } two;                                                

  template<typename Sig>                                                            
  struct select                                                                     
  {                                                                                 
  };                                                                                

  template<typename U>                                                              
  static one check (U*, select<char (&)[((&U::size)!=0)]>* const = 0);     
  static two check (...);                                                           

  static bool const value = sizeof (one) == sizeof (check (static_cast<T*> (0)));   
};



struct A{ };
int main ( )
{
    std::cout << has_size<int>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << has_size<A>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << has_size<std::vector<int>>::value << "\n";
}
```

but you have to be careful, this does neither work when `size` is overloaded, nor when it is a template. When you can use C++11, you can replace the above `sizeof` trick by `decltype` magic